# Angular 6 http post to Entity Framework on IIS fails to pass parameter in body

Tags: angular, entity-framework-4, httpclient

A `Get` request shows the basic framework functions correctly, but when I try to do a `Post`:

[image]

`OnSubmit(evt)` evt is the formgroup; Chrome Debugger:

[image]

THEN a few lines later: (http is bound to httpclient)

[image]

Entity Framework POST code:

```
    // POST api/Registration/NewUser/<registration object>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("NewUser")]
    public string Post([FromBody]_Registration newUser)
    {
        var Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        newUser.RegistrationId = Id.ToString();  << Good to here, but newUser is null
```

Using Postman to send a dummy record, the record makes it into the Post function.
The Id is calculated, BUT newUser is null so it can’t continue.

How do I get it to receive NewUser from the “body” of the request?

Comment: Post a [mcve] **as text**.

Comment: Are you use HttpClient? (not the old deprecated http?)

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in the `URL`, there should be to `//` instead of single `/` after `:`

`http:/`

should be

`http://`

Comment: Wow... I can tell you how long I stared at that and didn't see it; I will fix it and let you know if that was it.  :-)  Yogi